# Sliding glass door stuck closed

Tags: sliding-glass-door

I am buying a condo and it has a small deck.  There is a sliding glass door from the kitchen to the deck and it is stuck closed.  Stuck as in won't move even a fraction of an inch.  A couple of us tried and it wouldn't give at all.  I think it probably hasn't been opened in years.

There's nothing obviously wrong with it, such as being rusted or painted shut.  If this makes any difference it is about 30 years old.  One possibility that occurred to us is that the (cheap-looking) lock is stuck in the "locked" position.  There is an itty-bitty lever, and it will move, but not very far.  Less than 45 degrees.

Is there anything to do to diagnose what's wrong without breaking it or, probably worse, having it end up stuck in the open position?

---

More info: yes, having the seller take care of it would be ideal, but the seller has already moved out of state and will probably just knock the price down a bit in return for me doing the repair.  I'm not sure how big a deal this is or how much money to ask for.

Comment: Or there is a second more secure lock that you haven't discovered.  Sliding glass door are notoriously insecure with the lock they come with.  There are many strategies both commercially available and home brew to make the door more secure.

Comment: Photos might aid diagnosis.

Comment: I'd be asking the seller to deal with it. If it doesn't have a door it doesn't have a deck.

Comment: Make sure you examine every inch of frame to door contact. One common method of securing unused doors is to run a screw through both the door and frame

Comment: Perhaps the previous owner put a jam into the door track. A length of metal or wood between the non-lock side of the slider and the other end of the finish opening will have just this effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't budge it at all,  it most likely is the lock. Difficult to advise you on how to handle the lock without seeing it. If possible post a photo of the lock.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63194)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Why isn't, "If you can't budge it at all, it most likely is the lock," not an "answer?"

Comment: @LeeSam -- this is too speculative overall (the first part starts off OK, but an answer shouldn't ask for more stuff, as a rule)